# Java JDK 16.0.1 installer crashing without even starting the wizard

Tags: java, windows

I'm trying to install Java JDK 16.0.1. When I double-click the install file in the `Downloads` folder, it prompts me to allow changes, then does absolutely nothing.

I did some digging around in my `%appdata%` folder to look for crash reports/logs. It turns out every time I double-click the install file, it crashes with:

> Exception Code: 0xC0000005
>
> Exception Information: The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access.

I do have Java Runtime Environment 1.8.0_291 installed, but that shouldn't prohibit the JDK installer, should it?

I also do have Java Runtime Environment 1.8.0_241 installed, and can't seem to be able to uninstall it. Could this be the problem? When trying to uninstall it, it looks for `jre 1.8.0_241patch.msi`, but can't find it.  Regardless, this first issue shouldn't be a result of this old JRE install, correct?

Comment: This may be a better question for superuser, but try the following, 1) download it again just in case there was an issue, 2) Restart the PC so that nothing is hooked into the folder/installer, and so there are no conflicting/running installations that have stalled, and 3) copy the installer to a different folder directly on your main drive and give it another go.

Comment: Asking about installing programming tools such as the JDK is on topic here. There's no need to move the question to Super User.

Comment: Still doesn't work.  I am getting the same exception code and information.  I found this in the crash dumps folder in my %appdata%.  The only thing I can think of is to totally reset my PC and install a fresh Windows with nothing on it, but I want to see if I can find a better solution first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this on the OpenJDK bug system:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8202316

for that user it was happening with the JDK 8 installer but the behavior sounds identical to the issue that you're having.  In that post the original poster says "Problem solved. JDK 8u162 installer didn't remove all registry values of 8u152."

Now, I don't know why that's an issue; multiple JDKs *should* be able to peacefully coexist, but it might be worth a shot in your case before going to the length of doing a fresh reinstall of windows:

- uninstall the JRE 8 version (your 1.8.0... version)
- use tool or manually clean up any leftover java registry keys if necessary
- reboot PC
- try JDK 16 installer again

If you truly just have a JRE of version 8 and not a full-blown JDK, you could try using the java uninstall tool here:
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/uninstall_java.html

Also, I did find this old page about manually tracking down java registry entries (from 7.0 and older):
https://java.com/en/download/help/manual_regedit.html

Well, hope this helps.  Be sure to let us know whether you get it solved, I'm curious to know.  Thanks!

Comment: THANK YOU!  Yes so my old version of Java was the problem so removing it with the tool that you recommended worked.  Thank you!